# Combinatorics and principle of inclusion and exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I just want to ask if there is any way to distinguish whether a problem is solved with the principle of inclusion and exclusion or combinations or permutations. Is there any way I can find out if I look at an problem?

I know that it is not a concrete question, only sometimes I don't know which principle / formula to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times, a problem can be approached by inclusion-exclusion or just by directly counting with permutations and combinations. However, inclusion-exclusion can often make a problem much easier to solve.

Inclusion-Exclusion occurs when you can rephrase a question so you are trying to count the union of many sets. For example with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (ie. the number of permutations where no element is mapped to itself), it is not immediately clear this could be tackled by inclusion-exclusion. However, if you phrase it as defining the set $S_i = \#\text{permutations with element }i\text{ fixed}$, and then count $|S_1\cup S_2\cup\cdots\cup S_n|$, you will get the complement of the number of derangements. When phrased this way, it is much clearer that you would like to use inclusion-exclusion, as you are now trying to count the size of a union.

The trick is finding the right restatement of a problem so you are counting unions. This just takes practice to do.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, I will try to look at the problems in that way